# Convert Json String to json Arrays in angular 6

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular6

Hi I want to convert the RestController Response which is in Json String to json array here is my json array sting which i have printed in console.

```
'{"Impressions":["Budget","CTR","Campaign","Campaign state","Clicks","Conv. rate"],"Clicks":["Budget","CTR","Campaign","Campaign state","Clicks","Conv. rate"],"Revenue":["Budget","CTR","Campaign","Campaign state","Clicks","Conv. rate"]}'
```

I want to convert it to json array so that i can iterate it,

My requirement is to iterate the array and print key as label and value as slect options

Example:

Impression as label and "Budget","CTR","Campaign","Campaign state","Clicks","Conv. rate" as select options.

Here is my code for iteration

```html
<div>
   <form *ngFor ="let map of mapper">
      <mat-form-field>
         <mat-select placeholder="{{map}}">
            <!--<mat-option>None</mat-option>-->
             <mat-option *ngFor="let option of map"  [value]="option"> 
                {{option}}
             </mat-option>
         </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
</div>
```

my .ts class

```js
this.clientService.getHeaders().subscribe(
      (res) => {
          console.log(res);
          let resSTR = JSON.stringify(res);
          let resJSON = JSON.parse(resSTR);
          this.mapper=Array.of(resJSON._body);
          console.log(this.mapper);
          this.ismapped=false;
      }
);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Venomy I want to convert Json String in to Json array of type User defined Object class and use that array to iterate in *ngfor

Comment: You mean JSON string to JavaScript array. There's no such thing as a JSON array/object.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.clientService.getHeaders().subscribe(
  (res) => {
      console.log(res);
      let result= <any>res;
      this.mapper= result;
      console.log(this.mapper);
      this.ismapped=false;
  }
);
```

No need to go into stringifying and then parsing. Just cast the response to **any** and then you can use it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
let str = '{"Impressions":["Budget","CTR","Campaign","Campaign state","Clicks","Conv. rate"],"Clicks":["Budget","CTR","Campaign","Campaign state","Clicks","Conv. rate"],"Revenue":["Budget","CTR","Campaign","Campaign state","Clicks","Conv. rate"]}'

Object.keys(JSON.parse(str)).map(arr => {
  return `${arr}: ${JSON.parse(str)[arr].join(', ')}`;
});
```

Do whatever logic you want in return statement. Return it as a string, or as an array, or as an object.

Comment: Hi Alex thanks for quick response, I have created a model MapHeader 
export class MapHeader {
  public Budget: string;
   public CTR: string;
   public Campaign: string;
   public Orders: string;
   public Clicks: string;} 
I want array to assign to this model for which I wrote
  this.mapper= Object.keys(JSON.parse(str)).map(arr => {
              return `${arr}: ${JSON.parse(str)[arr].join(', ')}`;
                }); 
this is throwing an error Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'MapHeader[]'.
so that i can use mapper in html for *ngfor loop

Comment: Are you sure you need class here? I think interface is enough export interface MapHeader {
  Budget: string;
  CTR: string;
  Campaign: string;
  Orders: string;
  Clicks: string;
}

Comment: I'am completely new to angular I'am not understanding what you reffering to. could you explain me?

Comment: i tried with string[] and able to get array while iterating again i got an issue 
Cannot find a differ supporting object 'Campaign:  Budget, CTR, Campaign, Campaign state, Clicks, Conv. rate ' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: If you want to set custom type like MapHeader[], then use interface, not class: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html Test your data with simple <p *ngFor="let element of arr">{{element | json}}</p> and then transform data to the desired format

Comment: "Impressions:Budget, CTR, Campaign, Campaign state, Clicks"
"Clicks:Budget, CTR, Campaign, Campaign state, Clicks" this is what is getting printed how can i loop this again and print Impression as label and Budget, CTR, Campaign, Campaign state, Clicks as select option